# how to stop a recursive method after finite no. of recursions in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Hi I am new to javascript. I am having a recursive method as shown below

```
function index() {

// done some code here

$.ajax({

       url: 'foo.htm',

       success: function( response ){

           // do something with the response

           index(); // recursion

       }
   });
```

I want to stop that recursion exactly after 10 iterations. how can I do this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're new to programming as well? Use a counter with "tries left" as an argument and `0` for the base case of your recursion.

Comment: Maybe [this page](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/loops/5/1) will help.

Answer (score 4):

Like this :

```
function index(c) {
    if (c>10) return;
    // done some code here
    $.ajax({
           url: 'foo.htm',
           success: function( response ){
               // do something with the response
               index((c||0)+1); // recursion
           }
       });
}
```

You can call it as

```
index();
```

the counter will be automatically initialized at first increment.

---

Another pattern, useful when the number of calls may change, is to pass a decrementing counter :

```
function index(nbIterations) {
    if (!nbIterations) return;
    .ajax({
       url: 'foo.htm',
       success: function( response ){     
           index(nbIterations-1);
        }
    });
}

index(10)
```

Comment: Is the `c||0` necessary(guessing it means c or 0) ? Would c not be set the first time the function is called ? Genuinely curious as i'mnew to javascript.

Comment: @Jidder c is initially undefined. undefined+1 is NaN

Comment: if (c > 10) will cause a reference error on the first iteration. Should put 'c = c || 0;' before

Comment: Thanks! I thought you would have to pass the variable as the function was defined with it, similar to `David`s answer.

Comment: @Jidder: Technically you still *can* pass the initial value.  I like how this answer cleverly hides that so you don't always *need* to.  The choice of which approach to take in that regard is a matter of personal preference and the semantics of the function, really.  The structure of the terminating condition is still the same.

Comment: @David I realise that now, made an (incorrect)assumption as in most languages i have seen you have to pass the defined amount of args to a function or overload them.

Answer (score 2):

Any recursive function needs a "terminating condition" to stop recursion.  In general the format might look something like:

```
functionName() {
    if (terminatingCondition) {
        return;
    }
    performLogic();
    functionName();
}
```

To extrapolate into your code:

```
function index() {
    // terminating condition goes here

    // logic goes here
    $.ajax({
       url: 'foo.htm',
       success: function( response ){
           // more logic goes here

           index(); // recursion
       }
    });
}
```

What is that condition?  When *should* it terminate?

> I want to stop that recursion exactly after 10 iterations.

Then a counter should do the trick:

```
function index(iteration) {
    if (iteration > 10) {
        return;
    }

    // logic goes here
    $.ajax({
       url: 'foo.htm',
       success: function( response ){
           // more logic goes here

           index(iteration + 1); // recursion
       }
    });
}
```

Then call it with an initial seed value:

```
index(1);
```